# How does password expiration with a hosted Subversion (svn) repository work?

Tags: linux, svn, authentication, passwords, repository

I just uploaded my local svn file repository to an svn host. I notice that when checking out the code to my local (Linux) computer I have to provide my username and password (as expected) but subsequent operations (checkout, commit, log, etc.) does not require any authentication, so I take it that after initial login I stay logged in for some time.

My questions related to this are:

1. How long do I stay logged in like this?
2. What would trigger my access to the repository to expire?
3. Can I manage the expiration time, and if so, is it done server side, or in my local subversion configuration?

I'm running svn 1.7.9 on Ubuntu 13.10 Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How long do I stay logged in like this?

You are not *logged in*. Your authentication tokens are saved somewhere under `~/.subversion/auth`.

> 2) What would trigger my access to the repository to expire?

If you remove the file under `~/.subversion/auth` which stores your password for the particular repository, then you will have to reenter the password again.

> 3) Can I manage the expiration time, and if so, is it done server side, or in my local subversion configuration?

That really depends on how authentication is configured on the server side.

Btw, you can prevent Subversion from saving your authentication tokens if you checkout using `--no-auth-cache`.

**UPDATE**

There is a lot more to this, as @BenReser points out:

> Realize that the password is not necessarily stored under ~/.subversion/auth. We support a variety of platform specific credential storage (Windows Crypto API, OS X Keychain) and even in 1.8 GPG Agent. The GPG Agent case would behave somewhat like what he's envisioning, where the password is cached only for a certain amount of time, which he could configure. There is also NTLM/Kerberos support that may behave like a single sign on as well. So frankly it's really hard to answer this question without more details about his configuration.

Comment: Oh thanks. That was helpful! So basically I will retain access to the repo (without having to re-authenticate) forever (unless there are restrictions server side). Correct?

Comment: Yes, until something changes on server side. For example if your password changes on the server, that will also force you to re-authenticate.

Comment: Realize that the password is not necessarily stored under ~/.subversion/auth.  We support a variety of platform specific credential storage (Windows Crypto API, OS X Keychain) and even in 1.8 GPG Agent.  The GPG Agent case would behave somewhat like what he's envisioning, where the password is cached only for a certain amount of time, which he could configure.  There is also NTLM/Kerberos support that may behave like a single sign on as well.  So frankly it's really hard to answer this question without more details about his configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the original question with my system configuration.

Comment: On Ubuntu, by default, I think your credentials will be stored by the gnome keyring manager or something like that. The keyring is activated when you login, and it will probably cache your Subversion credentials. You can probably clear your credentials from the keyring manager. I don't know if you can configure it to expire because I don't have an Ubuntu here to test, but it's quite possible you can. You can find the keyring manager somewhere in the privacy settings of your account.